# How build a static library with maximum compatibility on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm writing a static library for ios developers.

How build a static library with maximum compatibility on iOS? In other words, support different types of projects in future. 
Such as, 3.0~ version, ARC/non-ARC project, xib/storyboard, simulator/iphone/ipad.

What are the most important things I should consider?

1. set deploy target to check compatibility?
2. use 'lipo' to merge tow platform lib?
3. do not use ARC in my code?

any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: as I said, iOS 3.0~ version, ARC/non-ARC project, xib/storyboard, simulator/iphone/ipad, arm6/arm7/i386.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: http://atastypixel.com/blog/an-xcode-4-template-to-create-universal-static-libraries/

I hope it helps!

At least, it will help you with the "universal" (arm6/arm7/i386) part.

Comment: Worked for me.  The github link is here  https://github.com/michaeltyson/iOS-Universal-Library-Template/tree/779b89f891cb0ae7288273541702341dc4ed81a8